# Why do bitmap images look blurred on Retina display?

Tags: retina-display

I do not have a Retina-device, but I've been seeing this discussion online. I have read about solutions that serve 2x image sizes to devices with Retina display, to ensure that bitmaps don't get blurred.

However, I do not understand how this works. First, as I've read, I'm assuming that Retina displays have four times the pixel density (two squared). So, this means, each pixel for a normal display is replaced by four in Retina, while they occupy the same physical space in totality.

Now, I'll refer to an article by SmashingMagazine (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/). They've used an image here to explain the concept: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/css-device-bitmap-pixels.png

They say that, since Retina has four times more pixel density, it multiplies the bitmap's pixels into four pixels each, and this makes the image lose detail.

However, in both cases (4 pixels or 1 pixels), the physical size of a "colored block" is still the same. Then, where is the loss in fidelity? A bitmap pixel is still being represented by the same physical size.

That's how I'm looking at it right now. Obviously, I'm making some sort of an assumption that is not allowing me to understand the concept. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: 1:4 should be a clear and lossless resample, they must do a gaussian blur or some other anti alias to break up the square blocks

Comment: I have the very same question! I can't get my head around it. Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: I think he put the wrong picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In explaining how a standard raster image is upscaled on a retina display, the article states:

> Because a bitmap pixel can’t be further divided, it gets multiplied by
>   four on Retina displays to preserve the same physical size of the
>   image, **losing detail along the way**.

This is misleading, and your initial understanding is correct. A retina display has four times the pixel density of a standard display, so a single pixel on a standard display corresponds to four pixels (2x2) on a retina display, which is the same physical size. There is no loss in detail, and in fact the image they include right below that statement demonstrates this:

[image: Device Pixels]]

Now, what makes this confusing is that if you look at the same raster image on a standard display and a retina display side-by-side, they don't look identical: the image does indeed look *blurrier* on the retina display. But contrary to what the article says, this is not because the image "loses detail," but rather because Apple applies some sort of smoothing algorithm to the image when it's upscaled.

---

So the question is, why does Apple do this?

I don't know of a technical reason why this is necessary; if anything, smoothing the image must add at least a minimal amount of overhead.

There is, however, a very good *marketing* reason to do this: it makes the difference between standard and retina graphics more noticeable and pronounced.

That kind of sounds like a gimmick, but it's actually important. Apple is very good at using a "carrot and stick" approach to make consumers and developers adopt new features, and this is a great example of that. The "carrot" is the higher quality of the retina display - who doesn't want a sharper picture? - while the "stick" is that if you as a developer don't update your app, it'll look terrible (especially alongside other apps that have already been updated).

So this approach creates incentive for developers to update their apps, which in turn makes the retina display a bigger selling point for consumers, which in turn generates further demand for developers to update their apps. It's a virtuous cycle, and as a result, I haven't encountered a single non-retina Mac app in *years*.